# VS2008 + MVC2 RC + L2S or VS10Beta2 + MVC2 Preview 2 + EFv4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm starting a new project which must have a working prototype within 10 days. The project should be cutting edge and I'd love to use latest tech, especially EFv4.
But, also I like new MVC2 features like ForEdit and easier validation implementation (for Areas I don't care).

MVC2 RC is out for VS2008 and works on VS10Beta 2 too, but "tooling is not". VS2010 uses old Preview 2 tooling, but I don't see anything missing...

Can someone who tried Preview 2 and RC summarize for me is there any important change in MVC2 RC (except for Areas tooling) that got changed and that should push me to stay with VS2008 and use L2S instead EFv4?

What would you go with?

Also, I've noticed Linq2Sql classes can be extended (as they are partial) so POCO is maybe not that important as I've thought.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this but doesn't MVC2 RC come with a change log?

Comment: It does, indeed, but not with the "VS tooling" change log. :)

Comment: If you ride the crest of the wave then you are going to get wet, you can't avoid not having the tooling built into you IDE especially if your IDE is Beta as well. Your question boils down to, do you want the tooling or not, or VS2008 or VS2010. If you don't have a target project in mind, even if it's just a play project, which can drive your technology decisions then it'll be a wonderful waste of time. In my experience 'shotgun learning' (not clear direction) is only an excuse to waste time, without application the knowledge gained is generally superficial at best.

Comment: There is a target project, very specific and will be (must be) in production very soon.

Comment: - this matter is now outdated since all the tools went production - deletition is a viable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is going to Production soon, then skip on the VS 2010 Beta, and use VS 2008.  I have experience lots of bugs with MVC2 Preview 2 and VS 2010, and it would not be worth your time to use 2010 for that reason.

I would use MVC2 RC, since it has the RenderAction method, which is VERY useful.

And if you are going with 2008, use Linq to SQL (I was not a big fan of EF1, but I am really looking forward to EF4).

Otherwise, wait until Feb for the 2010 RC and use that.

[MVC 2 Breakdown](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) - I know for sure RenderAction is only in RC.

Comment: I had in mind to use VS 2010 Beta 2 for EFv4 model and introduce it trough a repository, create MVC2 on VS2008 and compile all on VS 2010 Beta 2 together with MVC2 DLL, which compiles fine with .NET 4 in VS 2010 Beta 2 (confirmed by Haacked).

Comment: If I was going EF, I would go v4, but all the bugs I have hit in VS2010, I would wait for the RC in Feb.  I just don't trust it.

Comment: What kind of bugs, can you mention 1 or 2 most critical?

Comment: VS would crash when I was on a CSS file and hit Ctrl-F.  At random times the Arrow Keys, Backspace, and Enter key would stop working.  Random crashes.  It was enough of a hassle to make convert my MVC project back to 2008.